# Cannot read property '0' of undefined in angular 6

Tags: json, typescript, codeigniter, angular6

I'm getting this error in console, ***Cannot read property '0' of undefined*** but still I'm getting the result as expected.

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="slider-product">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="{{featureProducts[0].img_path}}" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;">
      <span class="tag">{{featureProducts[0].cat_name}}</span>
      <div>
        <a class="title">{{featureProducts[0].name}}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> {{featureProducts[0].min_price}}
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the function in typescript file

```
getFeatureProducts(){
this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl+`/getFeatureProducts`)
  .subscribe(
    (data:any[]) => {
      if(data.length) {
      this.featureProducts = data;
      }else{
      this.featureProducts = null;         
    }
    }
    )}
```

featureProducts is declared inside the class as

```
featureProducts: any;
```

I know there is work around to this problem, like I can use multiple variables as below

in typescript

```
imgpath0 = this.featureProducts[0].imgPath;
```

And using this variable in html directly as

```
{{imgPath0}}
```

But this is not a better approach as I have lot of properties to be displayed in html and I cannot declare as many variables in ts.

**Note:** *I don't want to loop using 'for' in html. Instead I need to fetch the properties as we usually do in JSON.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf="featureProducts && featureProducts[0]"` and prevent rendering the div until `featureProducts` object gets populated.

```
<div class="slider-product" *ngIf="featureProducts && featureProducts[0]">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="{{featureProducts[0].img_path}}" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;">
      <span class="tag">{{featureProducts[0].cat_name}}</span>
      <div>
        <a class="title">{{featureProducts[0].name}}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> {{featureProducts[0].min_price}}
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```